# Estimating population size by mark-recapture method

Tags: probability, statistics

I took all the white balls out of a box and put them back after painting 27 of them red. Next time, I took 40 balls and found 12 red. Q: How many balls are there in the box?

It's too bad I didn't study for it. I only know it has to do with probability/statistics, but I don't know what aspect.

My answer is 27/x=12/40, so x=90. Is it right?

Comment: That is a possible approach, though note it sometimes would  not give an integer estimate (e.g suppose you had found $11$ red rather than $12$) and sometimes would give an infinite estimate (suppose you had found $0$ red).  Even in your example, it is only an estimate; there could be a different total number of balls (anything from $55$ upwards).

Comment: @Henry Do you have any idea to find a better estimator for the population size $N$ compared to the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE), discussed in my answer below?

Comment: @Amir An alternative could be to use a Bayesian prior for the number of balls, and then use the posterior distribution for a point estimate.  Your MLE approach is not unreasonable (I did not vote it down)

Comment: @Henry How a reasonable prior distribution can be defined for $N$, considering that it can be any arbitrary integer?

Comment: @Amir Anything you think reasonable - it will affect your result, as will your point estimator.  With an improper flat prior for $n$, the mean of the posterior is $101.4$, median $97$ and mode is $89$ or $90$ (corresponding to your MLE estimate).  With a prior proportional to $0.9^n$, the mean of the posterior is about $79.1$, median $78$ and mode $75$.  The advantage of a Bayesian approach is that it makes it easier to construct a credible interval: with the improper flat prior, you might get $[70,158]$ as a $95\%$ credible interval as this is right-skewed.

Comment: @Henry Thank you for the nice point! For the Bayesian case with improper flat prior, I could find the closed-form formulas of the mean and variance of the posterior distribution, for the example above the mean is 92, very close to 90 obtained by ML. You may check my updates below.

Comment: @Amir - in R `n=40:10^5;sum(dhyper(12,27,n-27,40)*n)/sum(dhyper(12,27,n-27,40))`  does not give $92$  but $101.4$ so I am not sure how you found your mean

Comment: @Henry 101.4 is correct, and I double-checked it in python. I used $\frac{(n-1)(m-1)}{k-2}.$  I mistakenly divided 26*39 by 11 (instead of 10).

Answer (score 0):

The method of marking some members of population to estimate the population's size $N$ is called *mark-recapture*, especially used by ecologists to determine animal population's size in an area. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture#:%7E:text=Mark%20and%20recapture%20is%20a,within%20the%20sample%20is%20counted.) for other statistical results. There are different statistical methods for estimating $N$. In the following, I explained two of them. The outcome of the first method is very similar to what you obtained.

**Maximum likelihood method**

Using the maximum likelihood (ML) method, $N$ can be estimated.

The likelihood function is

$$L(N;m,n,k) = \frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{N-m}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

where the right side is the probability that when drawing $n$ balls ($n=40$) from an urn with $N$ balls ($N$ is **unknown** here) consisting of $m$ red balls ($m=27$), exactly $k$ balls ($k=12$) out of $n$ balls are red (it is actually the PMF of the hypergeometric distribution).

The idea behind ML method is that to estimate the population size $N$ in a way that the probability of occurring the current observation (appearing $k$ red balls in the sample with size $n$) is maximized.

To determine $N$ that maximizes the likelihood function $L(N,m,n;k)$, we need to find the largest $N$ that satisfies the following inequality:

$$\frac{L(N,m,n;k)}{L(N-1,m,n;k)}\ge 1.$$

This can be simplified to (if $k>0$)

$$N\le \frac{nm}{k}.$$

Hence, the ML estimator of $N$ based on the observation $k$ is

$$\left\lfloor \frac{nm}{k} \right\rfloor, $$

which is greater than or equal to $n+(m-k)$, which is a lower bound on $N$ that one can certainly infer from the current data.

When $k=0$, then $kN\le nm $ holds for any $N$, thus the estimate of $N$ is the largest possible value for $N$, or infinity if there is no limit on $N$. In practice, this means that the number of marked members ($m$) is very small compared to the whole population size, and you need to increase the size of marked members in order to have a better understanding of the whole population's size.

The estimator is consistent in the sense that $\left\lfloor \frac{nm}{k} \right\rfloor \rightarrow N $ as $m \rightarrow N$, considering that $k \rightarrow n$ as $m \rightarrow N$.

In your case, the answer is $\left\lfloor \frac{40\times 27 }{12} \right\rfloor=90$, which is an estimation for $N$ based on the ML method, larger than $40+(27-12)=55$.

**Bayesian method**

As suggested by @Henry we could use the Bayesian method to estimate $N$. Considering an improper flat prior for $N$, the mean of the posterior distribution for $k≥3$ is
$$\frac{(n-1)(m-1)}{k-2},$$

which differs from the MLE estimator (after rounding 101.4, it is 101). Moreover, the variance of the posterior distribution for $k≥3$ is given by

$$\frac{(m-1)(n-1)(m-k+1)(n-k+1)}{(k-2)^2(k-3)},$$

which can be used for constructing confidence intervals (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Mark_and_recapture#Statistical_treatment) for more details).

I am not aware of any other prior distribution $p_N$, such as the geometric distribution, for which the mean of the posterior distribution given below has a closed-form solution:

$$\left[\sum_{i=n+m-k}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{i-m}{n-k}}{\binom{i}{n}}p_N(i) \right]^{-1} \sum_{i=n+m-k}^{\infty} i \frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{i-m}{n-k}}{\binom{i}{n}}p_N(i). $$

However, when the prior distribution is the geometric distribution with success probability $p$, the mode of the posterior distribution can be computed by finding the largest $X$ that satisfies the following inequality:

$$X^2p-X\left[(m+n)p-k\right]-(1-p)mn\le0.$$